# Partial Update in MongoDB C# Driver - Dictionary issue

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, partial

I'm trying to build a generic method to handle all my partial updates via MongoDB C# driver, using the following method:

```
public bool UpdateObject<T>(UpdatableObject<T> updatableObject)
    where T : new()
{
    var builder = GenerateMongoUpdateBuilder(updatableObject.ModifiedFields);
    var collection = GetCollection<T>();
    var result = collection.Update(Query.EQ("_id", BsonValue.Create(updatableObject.Id)), builder, new MongoUpdateOptions { Flags = UpdateFlags.Multi });
    return result.UpdatedExisting;
}

private static UpdateBuilder GenerateMongoUpdateBuilder(Dictionary<string, object> modifiedFields)
{
    var builder = new UpdateBuilder();
    foreach (var modifiedField in modifiedFields)
    {
        var type = modifiedField.Value.GetType();
        if (type.IsPrimitive || type.IsValueType || (type == typeof(string)))
        {
            builder.Set(modifiedField.Key, BsonValue.Create(modifiedField.Value));
        }
        else
        {
            builder.Set(modifiedField.Key, modifiedField.Value.ToBsonDocument());
        }
    }
    return builder;
}
```

I had to struggle for a while until I found the solution to handle primitive types via BsonValue and non-primitive types via BsonDocument. Everything worked well, until...We've created an object which holds a dictionary. The insert works perfectly, but once it goes into update (using this method) - it cannot be deserialized any more. Looking at the object in the Mongo before and after the update indicates that it's not the same object anymore - after the update it has additional _t field holds "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,[SomeObject, SomeObjectAssembly]]"

So I'm starting to question my implementation...

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Nir.

Comment: That sounds a lot like a bug. I suggest you get better repro instructions and head over to their [jira site](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP) to report it

Comment: What does Dictionary<string, SomeObject> ends up as when you do .ToBsonDocument() on it?

Comment: This is the result: { "_t" : "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,[SomeObject, SomeObjectdll]]", "_v" : { "f5030d52-cd70-404f-a3b4-072b6261e2c3" : { "_id" : 0, "Name" : "Test" }, ... additional entries here ...

Comment: @kelloti - Thanks, I opened an issue in the Jira site: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the courtesy of Robert Stam, the issue was resolved. It's all described in the Jira item.
Thank you!